# How can I list files that the current user can access?

Tags: command-line, permissions

For security auditing purposes I would like to go through my systems' users and make sure they don't have filesystem access to more than I'd prefer they did.

I'd like something that outputs in the `ls -l` format like but for just one user (and their groups):

```
r-x /var
r-x /var/spool
r-x /var/spool/cron
--T /var/spool/cron/atjobs
```

Once I have a vetted list of what a user *should* be able to see, I can generate this again for other user and see how they differ. Make sense?

I want to underline that this needs to *evaluate* the current user's natural, group and even ACL permissions. Essentially testing each stage. I'm not sure if I care about sticky bits and things like that over simple `drwx` but we'll see where this goes :)

Answer (score 2):

The best I've been able to build so far is using bash's tests:

```
find . -exec bash -c 'd=-;r=-;w=-;x=-; [[ -d {} ]] && d=d; [[ -r {} ]] && r=r; [[ -w {} ]] && w=w; [[ -x {} ]] && x=x; echo "$d$r$w$x {}"' \;
```

A sample of that output:

```
drwx ./dlls/mscoree/tests
-r-- ./dlls/mscoree/tests/metahost.o
-rw- ./dlls/mscoree/tests/metahost.c
-r-x ./dlls/mscoree/tests/mscoree_test-stripped.exe.so
-r-- ./dlls/mscoree/tests/testlist.c
-rw- ./dlls/mscoree/tests/Makefile.in
-r-- ./dlls/mscoree/tests/debugging.o
```

Comment: Well, you could use `-readable` to skip the `[[ -w {} ]]` test at least.