# Are there any packages that do all the recommended configuration settings for a secured server environment?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, software-center, security

I came across questions & articles like these: [1.) What Can Be Done To Secure Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146775/what-can-be-done-to-secure-ubuntu-server) ,  [2.) How to prevent your website from getting hacked.](http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/20070705.htm) which speak of many configuration settings for securing an ubuntu server. I just want to know if there are any packages which handle setting all these configuration at all different places & I could probably just maintain a central configuration spot. Are there any such tools ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special actions for ubuntu server or for another operating system server e.g.
Just know that security of your server is security of services used for access and performing operations on your server.

Special tools for this tasks are not demanded. Best way to perform this do tuning of special programs for your needs.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html

Also if you have gui on your server, you can use `gnome-control-center` there is can be placed things such as `apparmor` or other security tables.