# Graphical IP Blocker program for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I just set up a new server using Ubuntu 18.04

On the old Ubuntu server, I have always used IPBLOCK to set up extensive lists of IP addresses I wanted to block from connecting to the server and it has worked flawlessly for years and years.

I can't find any programs similar to this.  There are some programs with GUI's that interface with IPTables, but none nearly as nice a solution as IPBLOCK or IPLIST) were.

Does anyone know if IPBLOCK or IPLIST can be installed on Ubuntu 18.04 ?

If not, are there any similar programs I could install instead?

Comment: Here's something I wrote a while ago that might help, it's not graphical though.  https://askubuntu.com/a/983591/231142

Comment: That's looks interesting Terrance.  It's not as convenient as IPLIST or IPBLOCK but might be a workable substitute.

Comment: I'm actually very surprised so few see this as a very important topic.

Comment: I agree!  +1 for visual here.  Maybe someone might know of the graphical ways.  I have not looked into them personally.