# Some unnamed processes eat 100% CPU

Tags: server, openssh

My vps is running Ubuntu 16.04. Recently, I have found a lot of failed ssh connections in /var/log/auth.log.
I have enabled fail2ban and disabled password authentication. Now, there are some unnamed processes which use 100 % CPU load in my VPS. Before, I have installed nodejs and npm package using root.
Below is output of htop

[image: htop column: PPID SessionID PID username ...]

The process 1550 is a child of process 1, it forks many unnamed processes. I think they are bitcoin miners or malwares.
Does anyone know about them ? I'm suspicious of vulnerability in a nodejs package.
Thank all !

Comment: I think the question is more suited for [sf]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Can Be Done To Secure Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146775/what-can-be-done-to-secure-ubuntu-server)

Comment: I have read and followed along many tips before. However, it seems there is another vulnerability. And I want to know what above processes are.