# What steps must be taken to secure my Ubuntu installation from keyloggers and screen capture software?

Tags: security, firewall

I have a Ubuntu desktop. I want to protect my installation from software which can steal passwords I enter by logging keystokes or capturing the screen in case of a graphical on screen keyboard. I am following the following steps:

1) Making sure I only install new software using the 'apt' command.

2) Enabling the ufw firewall to block incoming.

Are these steps enough? Can I be assured that there is no keylogger or screen capture software on my system? Or do I need to take additional precautions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Can Be Done To Secure Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146775/what-can-be-done-to-secure-ubuntu-server) refers to server but the same principles apply.

Comment: @Graham I believe my question is more specific.

Comment: I hope I get some simple tips.